# Telerik mvc grid client template incorrect output with a placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid

I have the following client template...

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:showQuestionChoiceWindow('<#= QuestionId #>') class='t-button t-grid-edit'>Choices</a>").Title("");
```

When the above is rendered, I get the following output:

```
<a class="t-button t-grid-edit" 971405d2-a08a-436a-ab79-7e45961c5ffb')=""href="javascript:showQuestionChoiceWindow(">Choices</a>
```

Basically my string with a simple replacement has been moved around resulting in invalid syntax. Removing the placeholder corrects the syntax but I need the injected value.

Answer (score 1):

You could try separating the class declaration out and putting it in HtmlAttributes.

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:showQuestionChoiceWindow(<#= QuestionId #>)'>Choices</a>").Title("").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-button t-grid-edit" })
```

Comment: Yes, tried that in all my experimentation. It seems regardless how "sparse" I trim my syntax down to, the placeholder replacement will be invalid.

Comment: Maybe it is the quote marks around the questionid. Have you tried removing those?

Comment: I have not marked this question as answered as it was not, however, I gave up and went a different route rather than procrastinate with what looks like a bug with Telerik.

Comment: I did not answer just out of my head. I tested it, and it works in my project. I'm sorry it does not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are having nested `'` in your template hence the problem. Try this (notice that the href attribute uses `\"`):

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href=\"javascript:showQuestionChoiceWindow('<#= QuestionId #>')\"  class='t-button t-grid-edit'>Choices</a>").Title("");
```

Comment: Before posting I tried backslashing all quotes but to no avail. My current theory is I am using a 3 level deep grid and this feature is just broken in that combination. Thanks for the reply.